# How to share buffer (or image) between multiple VkDevice's?

Tags: vulkan

I have an application with a single `VkInstance`. Also I have the same physical device index, but different `VkPhysicalDevice` objects and hence different `VkDevice` objects. What would be the easiest and the most correct way to share `VkBuffer` or `VkImage` with multiple logical devices?

Comment: What do you mean by "same index, but different PD"?

Comment: @krOoze I can control the index of physical device, but I can't control the getting of a handle `VkPhysicalDevice`.

Comment: I also don't understand what You mean by "I can control the index of physical device, but I can't control the getting of a handle VkPhysicalDevice". In Vulkan You can only enumerate existing physical devices. You don't influence their order or index, nor You can create them. You can only acquire one of the available handles by the same proces - enumerating available physical devices.

Comment: I wanted to say that I can guarantee the same  _real_ hardware. Actually, it's all about Qt and QVulkanWindow - it handles device creation and I can ask to use a particular physical device by providing an index in an array returned from enumerating function.

Comment: @nikitablack Now it makes sense. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't do it, but maybe try using the **VK_KHR_external_memory** extension. It allows You to export non-Vulkan handles from Vulkan memory objects and provide such external memory during buffer or image creation.

This way You can create a memory object that can be "shared" between logical devices. In one device You create a buffer/image and memory object in a normal way. Then You export this memory to get a non-Vulkan handle. Then, in the rest of Your logical devices, You specify that You want an external memory to be used for a buffer/image.

[EDIT]

But to share a memory object You have to use the same physical device as indicated by the spec:

> only the same concrete physical device can be used when sharing memory

Comment: That works only if it is the same physical device, right?

Comment: Yes, I thought about this too, and actually I implemented Vulkan-OpenGL communication this way before. But I don't like this approach - it requires some platform handling and I hope there's simpler way since I'm staying on the same hardware, in the same process and the same API.

Comment: @krOoze Yes. From the spec: *only the same concrete physical device can be used when sharing memory*.

Comment: @nikitablack Unfortunately I don't know about any other way to share resources in Vulkan. Each resource You create can be used only with the same logical device this resource was created from. Specification doesn't allow resources to be used with other "parent/owner" objects.