# How to correctly share VkDeviceMemory? What is VkExternalMemoryBufferCreateInfoKHR for?

Tags: vulkan

This is a continuation of my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49920858/how-to-share-buffer-or-image-between-multiple-vkdevices) post. In short - I have multiple `VkDevice`'s (and multiple *everything* - swapchains, command buffers etc) and I want to render *the same* geometry with these resources, i.e. I don't want to upload the data multiple times. As @Ekzuzy pointed out I could use `VK_KHR_external_memory`. I tried and actually it works, but I have some questions remaining as well as debug layer complains.

This are the most important steps:

1. Include all required extensions:

   ```
   instanceExtensions.push_back(VK_EXT_DEBUG_REPORT_EXTENSION_NAME);
   instanceExtensions.push_back(VK_KHR_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_CAPABILITIES_EXTENSION_NAME);
   instanceExtensions.push_back(VK_KHR_GET_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_PROPERTIES_2_EXTENSION_NAME);
   instanceExtensions.push_back(VK_KHR_EXTERNAL_SEMAPHORE_CAPABILITIES_EXTENSION_NAME);
   deviceExtensions.push_back(VK_KHR_SWAPCHAIN_EXTENSION_NAME);
   deviceExtensions.push_back(VK_KHR_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_EXTENSION_NAME);
   deviceExtensions.push_back(VK_KHR_EXTERNAL_SEMAPHORE_EXTENSION_NAME);
   deviceExtensions.push_back(VK_KHR_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_FD_EXTENSION_NAME);
   deviceExtensions.push_back(VK_KHR_EXTERNAL_SEMAPHORE_FD_EXTENSION_NAME);
   ```
2. Create a device local memory with a data. It intended to be a
   shared memory:

   ```
   a) create_staging_buffer_and_memory
   b) copy_data_to_staging_buffer
   c) create_device_local_buffer_and_memory
   d) copy_staging_buffer_to_device_local_buffer
   e) create_memory_handle
   ```

   `VkBuffer` objects here are temporary and are destroyed after the
   copying is finished. Staging memory too. Device local memory created
   with `VkExportMemoryAllocateInfoKHR` structure in
   `VkMemoryAllocateInfo::pNext` field. Memory handle obtained with `vkGetMemoryFdKHR` call. After that step I have a memory with a data in the device and a handle pointing to it.
3. Create `VkBuffer` and `VkDeviceMemory` which should participate
   in actual rendering. Memory created with `VkImportMemoryFdInfoKHR`
   structure in `VkMemoryAllocateInfo::pNext` field, where I use the
   handle which I got earlier.
4. Finally record a command buffer where bind a buffer from step `3`.

As I wrote before - I see the output, but the debug layer tells me:

> layer MEM: vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(): Cannot read invalid region of
>   memory allocation 0x17 for bound Buffer object 0x16, please fill the
>   memory before using.

I'm not sure why. And how the layer knows that the memory is invalid. In any case it looks wrong to me and I should not worry about this warning. Or should?

Another question is about `VkExternalMemoryBufferCreateInfoKHR` which is used in `VkBufferCreateInfo::pNext`. The documentation is not clear to me what it does - all information it have is the type of some handle. Which handle? And the application works the same *with* and *without* this struct specified.

Update: it seems that the layer warning is a [bug](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/issues/2616).

Comment: Maybe official Vulkan tests will help You. Check here: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/VK-GL-CTS/blob/master/external/vulkancts/modules/vulkan/api/vktApiExternalMemoryTests.cpp and look for the `testBufferBindExportImportBind()` function. It uses a set of helper functions, I think inside them You should find what You are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. It helped a lot. But unfortunately the code does not explain what it does. For example, [the same](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/VK-GL-CTS/blob/master/external/vulkancts/modules/vulkan/vktExternalMemoryUtil.cpp#L979) `VkExternalMemoryBufferCreateInfoKHR` structure is used for both [export](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/VK-GL-CTS/blob/master/external/vulkancts/modules/vulkan/api/vktApiExternalMemoryTests.cpp#L3387) and [import](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/VK-GL-CTS/blob/master/external/vulkancts/modules/vulkan/api/vktApiExternalMemoryTests.cpp#L3396) buffers. But what is it?

Answer (score 3):

`VkExternalMemoryBufferCreateInfoKHR` is for creating memory that is shared across APIs, or potentially across Vulkan instances or devices *where the underlying physical device is the same*.

There is an example of using the external memory API to share texture image information between OpenGL and Vulkan in my examples repository [here](https://github.com/jherico/Vulkan/blob/cpp/examples/glinterop/glinterop.cpp).  This example uses the Win32 HANDLE versions of the API, but the functionality is equivalent to the FD versions, just with a different type for storing the identifier to be passed between different APIs.

> Another question is about VkExternalMemoryBufferCreateInfoKHR which is used in VkBufferCreateInfo::pNext

<strike>This structure is used to inform the vulkan instance that the buffer in question may be shared, which may impact how the Vulkan driver manages it internally.</strike>

I *think* this structure is used when a Vulkan buffer is being created *from* external memory.  During buffer (or image) creation, you'd use this structure to mark that the image would be backed by external memory, then instead of the normal allocation you'd set the `pNext` of the MemoryAllocateInfo to a `ImportMemoryHostPointerInfoEXT` instance containing the shared handle.  I suspect it's not used in my example because there I use Vulkan only for exporting, and the GL side does the importing.  If you're using Vulkan on both the export and import side, you may need it.

Comment: Thank you, I saw your example before and actually I used it as a starting point. But you're not using `VkExternalMemoryBufferCreateInfoKHR` in your code. Probably it's a typo and you mean `VkExportMemoryAllocateInfoKHR`.  And regarding a buffer with `VkExternalMemoryBufferCreateInfoKHR` - AFAIK you can't share a `VkBuffer` itself, only a `VkDeviceMemory` so I don't see the point in this structure.

Comment: That makes sense. But I believe you need to update the answer again. `VkExternalMemoryBufferCreateInfoKHR` is **not** for creating shared memory. `VkExportMemoryAllocateInfoKHR` is used for that. `ImportMemoryHostPointerInfoEXT` - I couldn't find any information about this extension, instead `VkImportMemoryFdInfoKHR` (for linux) is used for the memory that should import.